# Why does this hosts file entry only work with a browser and the host name?

Tags: windows, windows-7, ip, hosts

My workstation's `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file contains the following (hypothetical) IP address mapping:

```
111.222.33.444         sub.domain.tld
```

In Firefox I can successfully browse to the `sub.domain.tld` host name. Since I can browse to the host name...

1. Why can I **not** browse directly to the `111.222.33.444` IP address?
2. Why can I ping **neither** `111.222.33.444` nor `sub.domain.tld`?

Clearly I lack an understanding what the hosts file is doing.

Comment: Fair enough. Why does Firefox resolve the host address from the host name but not browse directly to the host address? Further, why does the ping functionality do neither?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can I not browse directly to the 111.222.33.444 IP address?

Chances are the server has a default virtualhost that's different than `sub.domain.tld`. That default virtualhost may be set up to reject your request.

> Why can I ping neither 111.222.33.444 nor sub.domain.tld?

`ping sub.domain.tld` will ping `111.222.33.444`, but a server isn't required to respond to ping. It (as well as you) may be firewalled off from ICMP traffic.